# Show another div if earlier div height<300px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on dynamic page where height of the page is concern.

So, What I want is if height of `<div id="a">` **< 300px** , **Then only show** new `<div id="b">`

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

- Mandar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#a").height()<300) {
      $("#b").show();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, what I understand, you more likely have to work that out with JavaScript.

```
if (document.getElementById('a').offsetHeight < 300) 
   document.getElementById('b').style.display = block;
```

don't forget to set `b` to display:none; as default